# Custom domains and SSL in azure

Tags: azure

**Hi,**

I need to create multiple domains in a single web app @ Azure.

How to approach this concept in azure?.

**Thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you should register domains and then go, for example, programmatic way. I would recommend that - below is the snippet of the code (C#) that will add domains to the webapp. But you can add your hostnames using http://portal.azure.com - Settings => Custom domains => Hostnames. (bring external domains).

1) Install the NuGet [Web Sites Management Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites/) into your project.

2) Get Azure Publish Settings file (for example, by using Powershell Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile). You will need that later (the value of the management certificate field inside of that file).

2) Instantiate WebSiteManagementClient. [That](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/src/ServiceManagement/WebSite/WebSiteManagement/Generated/Models/WebSiteUpdateParameters.cs) should help with the understanding of the code.

3) Next, the code is below. I just tested and it works. First, it lists the webspaces, then the websites inside of each of webspace, and you should copy and paste the website webspace into the

```
public const string base64EncodedCertificate = "ManagementCertificateValueFromPublishSettingsFile";
    public const string subscriptionId = "AzureSubscriptionId";

    static SubscriptionCloudCredentials getCredentials()
    {
        return new CertificateCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedCertificate)));
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebSiteManagementClient client = new WebSiteManagementClient(getCredentials());

        WebSpacesListResponse n = client.WebSpaces.List();
        n.Select(p =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("webspace {0}", p.Name);
            WebSpacesListWebSitesResponse websitesInWebspace = client.WebSpaces.ListWebSites(p.Name,
                  new WebSiteListParameters()
                  {
                  });
            websitesInWebspace.Select(o =>
            {
                Console.Write(o.Name);     

                return o;
            }).ToArray();
            return p;
        }).ToArray();

        Console.ReadLine();
        var configuration = client.WebSites.Get("WebSpaceName", "WebSiteName", new WebSiteGetParameters());

        configuration.WebSite.HostNames.Add("new domain");
        var resp = client.WebSites.Update("WebSpaceName", "WebSiteName", new WebSiteUpdateParameters() { HostNames = configuration.WebSite.HostNames });
        Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```